# No such file error in bash script to list files

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that lists all the files in a directory. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER_NAME=$1

if ! [ -d "$FOLDER_NAME" ]; then
    echo "Error: Folder does not exist!" 
    exit 0 
fi

FILE_NAMES=$("ls ${FOLDER_NAME}/*")

echo $FILE_NAMES
```

When i run my script with any directory (lets say .) the output shows

```
ls ./*: No such file or directory
```

But when I run that ls command in my shell in lists all the files correctly. I'm fairly new to bash. I don't understand what's wrong in the code.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you use double quotes in `FILE_NAMES=$("ls ${FOLDER_NAME}/*")`.
Note 1: using `"$1"` instead of `$1` will help you when you will face folders with spaces in their name;
Note 2: exit status 0 means success in Linux, you should use an other number instead.
Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER_NAME="$1"

if ! [ -d "$FOLDER_NAME" ]; then
    echo "Error: Folder does not exist!" 
    exit 1 
fi

FILE_NAMES=$(ls "$FOLDER_NAME"/*)

echo $FILE_NAMES
```